# Python decimal context for fixed point

Tags: python, decimal, fixed-point, exponent

I want to calculate with numbers having 3 places before and 2 places after decimal point (of course, 2 and 3 are configurable). I think it will be easiest to explain by examples:

0.01 and 999.99 are the lower and upper limit for positive numbers. Of course, there is also 0.00, and negative numbers from -999.99 to -0.01. Distance between every two consecutive numbers is 0.01.

7.80 + 1.20 should be 9.00, and 999.00 + 1.00 should be OverflowError. 0.20 * 0.40 should be 0.08, and 0.34 * 0.20 should be 0.07 (this can set a flag to indicate it was rounded, but it mustn't raise any exceptions). 0.34 * 0.01 should be 0.00 (same condition as the previous one).

In fact, I want "ints" from 0 to 99999, just written with a dot after third digit, scaled down 100 times when multiplying, and up 100 times when dividing. It should be possible to find a context exactly for that, right?

The problem is, I can't find the right setting for Emin, Emax, clamp, and prec that will do what I want. For example, I tried setting Emin and Emax to 0, but this raised too many InvalidOperations. The only thing I know is that rounding should be ROUND_HALF_EVEN. :-)

Comment: Since precision always applies to significant digits and not to digits before/after the decimal point (so six significant digits would allow both `12345.0` and `0.12345`), I think the best way would be to create a custom `int`-based class for this.

Comment: Yes, I guess prec should be 5 in my example. That's not the problem. The problem is, how to convince Decimal to have a _fixed_ point, not a floating one? I still refuse to believe decimal can't do that. The tagline says: "Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic". What does the "fixed point" mean if not exactly that?

Comment: Look at the very beginning - right after the title. :-) Yes, I know fixed point is a mythical beast somewhat, but sometimes people really do need it. It would be a shame to write a custom class if decimal can do that.

Comment: @Veky: Have you ever found a solution to your problem. I am also looking for the exact same thing you mentioned in the question, but am yet to find a way of doing it using an elegant, fast and not-error-prone solution using the `decimal` module despite many days spent on the issue...

Comment: No, and I'm quite sure it's impossible using only documented features. I just wrote my own, delegating to Decimal what I could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Q. Once I have valid two place inputs, how do I maintain that invariant throughout an application?
>
> A. Some operations like addition, subtraction, and multiplication by an integer will automatically preserve fixed point. Others operations, like division and non-integer multiplication, will change the number of decimal places and need to be followed-up with a quantize() step:

```
>>> TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2   # same as Decimal('0.01')
>>> a = Decimal('102.72')           # Initial fixed-point values
>>> b = Decimal('3.17')
>>> a + b                           # Addition preserves fixed-point
Decimal('105.89')
>>> a - b
Decimal('99.55')
>>> a * 42                          # So does integer multiplication
Decimal('4314.24')
>>> (a * b).quantize(TWOPLACES)     # Must quantize non-integer multiplication
Decimal('325.62')
>>> (b / a).quantize(TWOPLACES)     # And quantize division
Decimal('0.03')
```

> In developing fixed-point applications, it is convenient to define functions to handle the quantize() step:

```
>>> def mul(x, y, fp=TWOPLACES):
...     return (x * y).quantize(fp)
>>> def div(x, y, fp=TWOPLACES):
...     return (x / y).quantize(fp)    
>>> mul(a, b)                       # Automatically preserve fixed-point
Decimal('325.62')
>>> div(b, a)
Decimal('0.03')
```

Seems like the solution is to set precision to 5 and Emax to 2 and use those quantising functions.

```
con = decimal.getcontext()
con.prec = 5
con.Emax = 2
con.Emin = 0

try:
    Decimal(1) * 1000
except decimal.Overflow as e:
    print(e)
else:
    assert False

assert Decimal("0.99") * 1000 == Decimal("990.00")
assert div(Decimal(1), 3) == Decimal("0.33")
```

### Creating a Fixed Point Decimal Class

It seems like it's surprisingly easy to modify the decimal module to become fixed point (at the expense of losing floating point decimals). This is because the `Decimal` class is referenced by global name in the module `decimal`. We can pop in our down compatible class and things will work just fine. First you need to prevent python from importing the C `_decimal` module and make it use the pure-python implementation of the `decimal` module (so we can override a private method of `Decimal`). Once you've done that you only need to override one method -- `_fix`. It's called for every new `Decimal` that is created for which it is possible that it may not abide by the current decimal context.

**module set up**

```
# setup python to not import _decimal (c implementation of Decimal) if present
import sys

if "_decimal" in sys.modules or "decimal" in sys.modules:
    raise ImportError("fixedpointdecimal and the original decimal module do not work"
        " together")

import builtins
_original_import = __import__
def _import(name, *args, **kwargs):
    if name == "_decimal":
        raise ImportError
    return _original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
builtins.__import__ = _import

# import pure-python implementation of decimal
import decimal

# clean up
builtins.__import__ = _original_import # restore original __import__
del sys, builtins, _original_import, _import # clean up namespace
```

**main Decimal class**

```
from decimal import *

class FixedPointDecimal(Decimal):

    def _fix(self, context):
        # always fit to 2dp
        return super()._fix(context)._rescale(-2, context.rounding)
        # use context to find number of decimal places to use
        # return super()._fix(context)._rescale(-context.decimal_places, context.rounding)

# setup decimal module to use FixedPointDecimal
decimal.Decimal = FixedPointDecimal
Decimal = FixedPointDecimal
```

**tests**

```
getcontext().prec = 5
getcontext().Emax = 2
a = Decimal("0.34")
b = Decimal("0.20")
assert a * b == Decimal("0.07")
```

## Using a customisable context

The context class is used to keep track of variables used control how new decimals are created. This way each program or even thread will be able to set the number of decimal places it wants to use for its decimals. Modifying the `Context` class is bit more long-winded. Below is the full class to create a compatible `Context`.

```
class FixedPointContext(Context):

    def __init__(self, prec=None, rounding=None, Emin=None, Emax=None,
                       capitals=None, clamp=None, flags=None, traps=None,
                       _ignored_flags=None, decimal_places=None):
        super().__init__(prec, rounding, Emin, Emax, capitals, clamp, flags, 
                traps, _ignored_flags)
        try:
            dc = DefaultContext
        except NameError:
            pass
        self.decimal_places = decimal_places if decimal_places is not None else dc.decimal_places

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "decimal_places":
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __reduce__(self):
        flags = [sig for sig, v in self.flags.items() if v]
        traps = [sig for sig, v in self.traps.items() if v]
        return (self.__class__,
                (self.prec, self.rounding, self.Emin, self.Emax,
                 self.capitals, self.clamp, flags, traps, self._ignored_flags,
                 self.decimal_places))

    def __repr__(self):
        """Show the current context."""
        s = []
        s.append('Context(prec=%(prec)d, rounding=%(rounding)s, '
                 'Emin=%(Emin)d, Emax=%(Emax)d, capitals=%(capitals)d, '
                 'clamp=%(clamp)d, decimal_places=%(decimal_places)d'
                 % vars(self))
        names = [f.__name__ for f, v in self.flags.items() if v]
        s.append('flags=[' + ', '.join(names) + ']')
        names = [t.__name__ for t, v in self.traps.items() if v]
        s.append('traps=[' + ', '.join(names) + ']')
        return ', '.join(s) + ')'

    def _shallow_copy(self):
        """Returns a shallow copy from self."""
        nc = Context(self.prec, self.rounding, self.Emin, self.Emax,
                     self.capitals, self.clamp, self.flags, self.traps,
                     self._ignored_flags, self.decimal_places)
        return nc

    def copy(self):
        """Returns a deep copy from self."""
        nc = Context(self.prec, self.rounding, self.Emin, self.Emax,
                     self.capitals, self.clamp,
                     self.flags.copy(), self.traps.copy(),
                     self._ignored_flags, self.decimal_places)
        return nc
    __copy__ = copy

# reinitialise default context
DefaultContext = FixedPointContext(decimal_places=2)

# copy changes over to decimal module
decimal.Context = FixedPointContext
decimal.DefaultContext = DefaultContext
Context = FixedPointContext

# test
decimal.getcontext().decimal_places = 1
decimal.getcontext().prec = 5
decimal.getcontext().Emax = 2
a = Decimal("0.34")
b = Decimal("0.20")
assert a * b == Decimal("0.1")
```

Comment: Ok, I was afraid the answer would be something like that. Of course I saw that FAQ, but I supposed it was only for people who need mixed arithmetic, so "how to emulate fixed inside floating". I didn't think it's the canonical way to implement fixed-point-only. Honestly, it's ugly. Of course first thing I'll do is make a subclass that will define * and / to do exactly what mul and div do. Still, your answer was helpful because it showed me the asymmetry of Emin and Emax (and I guess 2 is 3-1 and not the number of decimal places:). Do you know maybe how to set con.clamp, BTW?

Comment: Subclassing `Decimal` is tricky. You will either have to subclass every method of `Decimal` that returns a `Decimal`, not just `__mul__` and `__div__`. Further you will need to be careful with binary operations using both  `Decimal` and `FixedPointDecimal` in your program.Depending on the order of operations the result may be a `Decimal` or `FixedPointDecimal`. Alternatively you could do `decimal.Decmal = FixedPointDecimal`, but this will prevent you from being able to use floating point decimals.

Comment: I know all that. That's why I'm so depressed by this. It would be _much_ easier for people who wrote decimal module to just have one more parameter in the context (in fact I think just another value for clamped would do the trick) that would enable fixed-point arithmetic. And regarding your last sentence, I would gladly give up floating point decimals, but I don't think reassigning decimal.Decimal would work that way. import really copies a module, and I change just my copy, not what decimal thinks Decimal is.

Comment: I've added some code that shows how to easily and simply override `Decimal` to make it fixed point. Hope that helps. Btw `import` does not copy a module. It checks to see if it's already imported and just assigns it to a name in the given namespace.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this earlier, I somehow missed your later update. Do you maybe have any info about clamp setting? I see you leave it at None in your solution... is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry I don't really know. The documentation suggests a value of 1 for compatibility with the IEEE spec. But all it seems to do is find ways to represent numbers outside the given exponents by changing the value of the coefficient (by multiplying or dividing by powers of 10). Which from your question is I thought I'd not something you wanted.

Comment: Of course. To explain why I was so obsessed with clamp: at the beginning it seemed like exactly what I needed. My initial thought was to put Emin = Emax and clamp =1, thus forcing all numbers to have the same exponent - but now it seems I really wanted opposite from that: I guess clamp = -1 would be a fantastic setting for what you did, if decimal ever decides to implement that. :-D

Comment: And yes, I see where the error in my pre-previous comment was: pure Python modules aren't copied and really are available for live surgery, but when I tested that, `_decimal` C module was imported and of course attribute setting didn't work there (though an error message instead of silently failing would be nice:). And I'm more than a bit sad for having to abandon speed in the name of correctness (using pure Python implementation). And third, it's incredible that they _have_ a perfect hook in place (`_fix` you found), yet they decided to not implement fixed point via it. :-(